# Como trazer outras colunas com GroupBy com LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

Eu tenho duas Tabelas:

1º Processo que contem ProcessoId e SituacaoProcessoId

2º SituacaoProcesso que contem SituacaoProcessoId e Descrição

Modelos:

```
public class ProcessoModel
{
    public int? ProcessoId { get; set; }
    public int? SituacaoProcessoId { get; set; }
    public virtual SituacaoProcessoModel SituacaoProcesso { get; set; }

}

public class SituacaoProcessoModel
{
    public int? SituacaoProcessoId { get; set; }      
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ProcessoModel> LstProcesso { get; set; }
}
```

Quero trazer a contagem de total de processos para cada tipo de situação, meu código abaixo já esta fazendo isso, porem eu quero que na Descrição venha a coluna Descrição da tabela de SituacaoProcesso e não o SituacaoProcessoId, como posso fazer isso?

```
var processo = db.TbProcesso
            .GroupBy(p => p.SituacaoProcessoId)
            .Select(p => new
            {
                Descricao = p.Key,
                Total = p.Count()
            });
```

Em my Sql eu consigo, o problema é fazer com LINQ

```
SELECT 
    sp.Descricao, COUNT(p.SituacaoProcessoId) AS Total
FROM
    processo p
        LEFT JOIN
    situacao_processo sp ON p.SituacaoProcessoId = sp.SituacaoProcessoId
GROUP BY p.SituacaoProcessoId
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tentou usar o `Join` do `Linq`? Algo como  `.Join(p.TbSituacaoProcesso, processo.SituacaoProcessoId, situacaoProcesso.SituacaoProcessoId, 
(post, meta) => new { TbProcesso = post, TbSituacaoProcesso = situacaoProcesso })`

Comment: Maurício, tem como postar os models `Processo` e `SituacaoProcesso`?

Comment: @Ricardo tinha tentado algumas coisas mas nada deu certo

Comment: @LINQ Pronto, postei os modelos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É só fazer uso das propriedades de navegação.

```
var processo = Processos
                .GroupBy(p => new 
                             { 
                                 p.SituacaoProcessoId, 
                                 Descr = p.SituacaoProcesso.Descricao 
                              })
                .Select(p => new
                {
                    Descricao = p.Key.Descr,
                    Total = p.Count()
                });
```

Comment: Funcionou quando eu troquei essa parte: p.SituacaoProcessoId, Descr = p.SituacaoProcesso.Descricao

Comment: Não entendi, @MauricioFerraz

Comment: Na sua resposta vc colocou : p.ProcessoId, Descr = p.SituacaoProcesso.Descricao, ai nao funcionou por que ele agrupou por ProcessoId ai eu alterei para p.SituacaoProcessoId, Descr = p.SituacaoProcesso.Descricao e ai sim funcionou, entendeu?

Comment: @MauricioFerraz ah, eu errei na hora de digitar

Comment: Corrigido perfeito Obrigado.